# What is the advantage of running a DNS server at home?

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-15

I'm planning on installing fedora 15 and several servers (http, ftp, svn, mail++) but I wonder what the advantage is by installing and running a DNS server on that same box?

Comment: Are you going to host any zones (domains) on the DNS server, or is it purely as a resolver?

Comment: I echo grawity.  [There are two kinds of DNS servers.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-server-roles.html)  They do quite different things, and the reasons for running them differ.  Which is the one that you want to know about?  You wouldn't expect people to answer a similar question for HTTP without your specifying whether you mean _proxy_ or _content_ HTTP service.  Don't expect people to likewise guess what kind of DNS service you are thinking of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of the advantages include:

- Localized DNS server can provide better performance because it deals directly with root servers
- Resources are dedicated only to the computers you authorized to use the DNS server (unlike the ISP's DNS servers which will be serving most of its customers and possibly dumping older records sooner {re-querying a zone that's not cached increases response times})
- You can add customized zones for other purposes (e.g., an intranet)
- Security can be better because someone else can't tamper with your cache (assuming you take reasonable steps to secure your system)
- If the ISP's DNS servers are down (typically very rare), it doesn't effect you

I run my own DNS servers at home, and also set them up for my clients who use Unix servers.

Comment: aside from those, you get experience running them ;).

Comment: @Journeyman Geek (+1):  Yes, that's a very important reason.  Thanks!